# Optional properties in optional classes VS Optional values in optional dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I noticed some interesting behavior when trying to access values of optional properties in optional classes VS trying to access the values of optional values in optional dictionaires.

It seems that in the former case you only need to unwrap once to access the value. However, in the latter case you have to unwrap twice to access the value. I was wondering why this is, and was hoping someone could provide me with some insight!

Below is an example accessing the value of an optional property in an optional class

```
class Cat{
    var food : Food?
}

class Food{
     var amount : Int?
}

var meowzer = Cat()
meowzer.food = Food()
meowzer.food?.amount = 10
var catFoodAmt = meowzer.food?.amount

print("\(catFoodAmt)")

if let catFoodCount = meowzer.food?.amount{
    print("\(catFoodCount)")
}
```

The result of the first print statement is:

```
Optional(10)
```

The result of the second print statement (after unwrapping) is:

```
10
```

Below is an example of accessing the value of an optional value in an optional dictionary

```
var dog : [String : Int?]?
dog = ["treat_count" : 10]

var dogTreatAmt = dog?["treat_count"]

print("\(dogTreatAmt)")

if let dogTreatCount = dog?["treat_count"] , dogTreatCountFinal = dogTreatCount{

    print("\(dogTreatCount)")
    print("\(dogTreatCountFinal)")

}
```

The result of the first print statement is:

```
Optional(Optional(10))
```

The result of the second print statement (after unwrapping once) is:

```
Optional(10)
```

The result of the third print statement (after unwrapping twice) is:

```
10
```

Why do I need to unwrap twice to access the desired value in the second case but not the first?

My guess is it has to do with that fact that if I were to have used a key other than "treat_count" (like "count" for example) then the value for that key would have been nil. However, I haven't been able to find a iOS "rule" or a better explanation on why this is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `[String : Int?]` is theoretical, practical any keys and values in a dictionary must not be `nil`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `Cat.food?.amount` returns `Int?` while `Dictionary<String, Int?>.subscript(String)` returns `Int??`.

This is because `Dictionary.subscript<Key>` returns `Element?`, and `Element` here is `Int?`. Thus you're getting one extra level of Optional.

Optional chaining just removes an extra Optional wrapping at the point that it's used. It doesn't collapse all Optionals. In one case you have two, collapsed to 1 (for one `?`) and in the second you have three, collapsed to 2 (for one `?`).

As vadian suggests, this would be a crazy Dictionary, so it's unlikely to come up in good Swift, but it can be reasoned about. If it weren't like this, you would lose information.

Comment: huh! I didn't know Dictionary.subscripty<Key> returned Element? Also, thanks for extra info about optional chaining!

Answer (score 0):

It actually makes sense : simply count the number of ?s :).

With you first example, the property is an optional where, in your second example, you have an optional dictionary where its key is a string and the value is an optional integer.

So if you want to access the value of the second example, you have to unwrap the dictionary, then unwrap whatever there is in that dictionary for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. Let's think the type definition of a Dictionary:

```
struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value>
```

And the signature of the subscript function:

```
public subscript (key: Key) -> Value?
```

Which can also be thought of as:

```
public subscript (key: Key) -> Optional<Value>
```

Armed with this, let's look at your dictionary, which is typed as:

```
Dictionary<String, Int?>
```

Or more explicitly

```
Dictionary<String, Optional<Int>>
```

Where `Value` is of type `Optional<Int>`, and `Key` is of type `String`

So if we substitute in the key, the subscript definition is:

```
subscript (key: String) -> Optional<Value>
```

And if we substitute it in the `Value`, we get what you are seeing:

```
subscript (key: String) -> Optional<Optional<Int>
```

---

Now, let's break down your code and to make everything fit together:

```
var dogTreatAmt = dog?["treat_count"]
```

Since `dog` is optional, no matter what you call on it, the result will also be wrapped in an Optional, which we will temporarily think of as `Optional(FunctionReturn)`

Now let's take a look at `FunctionReturn`, which is the subscript function. We have already determined that this will return `Optional<Optional<Int>>`

Which means that really you're returning `Optional<Optional<Optional<Int>>>`, however as noted by Rob Napier, 
"Optional chaining removes an extra Optional wrapping at the point that it's used".